# Mail server setup on DigitalOcean with CloudFlare

Tags: ubuntu, email-server

I'm trying to make my own mail server. The problem is, it doesn't work at all. I've tried to install postfix, wich didn't work (Couldn't receive mails) and then I tried Exim, didn't work too...

I'm using a [DigitalOcean](https://m.do.co/c/997ee5c5363d) server (the server of 5$/mo.) And a cloudflare normal account.

So what I want is that I can send and receive e-mails from my own domain.
I'll integrate later on a function to receive mails in my web app...

But right now, I'm kinda stuck on the setup, and usage.

This is my DNS on CloudFlare: 
[image: DNS]

Hidden is my IP adress of my server.

I can't sent nor receive any e-mail traffic...
I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04 x64**.

Could someone explain me in a really good way how I should handle and build my own e-mail server?

If there is something wrong with my DNS, pleae tell me how and what I need to fix.

Kindest regards,

Robin

Comment: From my DNS, there is the address from DigitalOcean server (128.199.x.x), not the cloudflare address. Did you activate your configuration ?

Comment: I have also a 128.199.x.x adress (from DigitalOcean). What do you mean by activate?

Comment: I am sorry : do you use the caching possibility from cloudflare ? If not, I can not access to your port 25 in tcp : it is filtered.

Comment: I have currently not installed any mailing (receiving and sending) software installed on my server. Because I don't know HOW I should configure everything. That's kinde my question...

Comment: You need to try, and ask us when there is a problem. Your DNS configuration is OK, so install, configure and give us the errors you see in the logs.

Comment: If I do `telnet mail.rallypodium.be smtp` It just says 'Trying 192.168.1.10...' And it can't connect, I've used this tutorial: http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: I have the same problem. There is a firewall which drops the packets between the machines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35494/discussion-between-robin-r-and-dom).

Comment: Problem solved. Some typo's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CloudFlare DNS settings, make sure that you have a "gray" cloud for the `mail` A record, in order for connections to that host to bypass CloudFlare and go to your mail server directly. CloudFlare does not proxy SMTP traffic.

An example of a working domain:

[image: CloudFlare DNS settings]